# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltinfo

Tags: command-line

I've a problem installing [coriander](https://github.com/hughperkins/coriander).
The error says it can't find *ltinfo* and I've tried most of the suggested ways in the other threads none seems to work that if I executed them correctly.
Am I missing some libraries?
I'm fairly new to the linux stuff.
I'm using a fresh copy of Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS

[image: Terminal]

Comment: Please do not add pictures of text. Post text as text and use the formatting tools to highlight terminal output.

Comment: Install the package `libncurses-dev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm guys
I was missing a library called libtinfo
details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137879/link-error-cannot-find-ltinfo-on-ubuntu-12-04-on-a-32-bit-arm-processor
In case someone ran into the same problem